# Screenorientation in addview()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I add view by addView() and I want to block screen orientation on that view to portrait.
I tried:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP;
    params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    LinearLayout glass = new LinearLayout(this);
    glass.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.glass6);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(glass, params);
```

It doesn't work.
How can I do it?
Also how can I do that my new view do not dissapear after app close?

Comment: please be more specific what you wish to do ..........

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
glass.setOrintation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` or android:screenOrientation="portrait" in your manifest file.To restrict your activity to be viewed in `portrait` or `landscape` mode.

Comment: See using this code you can restrict your activity to be viewed in landscape or portrait mode.And important thing is your service is not visible it runs in background.So that means suppose if you trying to start any activity then it will visible in either landscape or portrait mode as per your requirement.